# How to send data to a previously included PHP file?

Tags: php, header, head

I have a *header.php* and a *footer.php* file. My HTML header is in *header.php*  and I have an *index.php* file.

I’m using so (*index.php*):

```
require 'header.php';

$example_code = 'example';

︙

require 'footer.php';
```

And my *header.php*:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
     ???
  <title>
  <meta name="description" content="???" /> 
   <meta name="keywords" content="???" /> 
 </head>
<body>
︙
```

I want to send some data from *index.php* to *header.php* to print it there (see the `???`). I’m thinking of the `header()` function but I can’t see any example in the PHP manual.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you could do is separating logic from presentation. Using an MVC approach, where you take care of all logic in one file, and then display the outcome of what you've done in a presentation only layer.

Besides that, if you want to keep your approach, what you simply have to do is to **make assignments before header.php is included**. So, suppose you want to change your page title, this is what you need to do:

index.php

```
<?php
$title = 'My Page Title';
$description = 'My meta description';
$keywords = 'keyword list';
include('header.php');

?>
```

header.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
     <?php echo $title; ?>
  <title>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" /> 
   <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" /> 
 </head>
<body>
```

It's as simple as that. Just keep in mind **you can't make assignments to a page/script, AFTER such has been included**

Again, though, I'm trying to answer you, not necessarily suggesting this approach. If your application has just a couple of pages, that's ok. If it's bigger (or going to be), something like the MVC pattern (two-step view pattern) is a better alternative IMHO.

Comment: Glad you've found such techniques useful. Separating logic from presentation can help you especially with maintenance of your app. Just a word on caution next time on using the header word - especially if coupled with the header() function, which works on the other kind of heading - as it might be a source of misunderstanding. :-)

Comment: Sure, always wise to use it (esp if input comes from outside). I don't think that's needed on strings mentioned above, though. And not strictly related to question. We could otherwise spend hours looking for ways to refactor this code. :-) I think the point in the question was about assignment and calling order, not on other writing clean code best practices. We could otherwise write a book down here :-D Good tip of yours, though!

Comment: hmm?, `$title = 'My top << supersite.com >>';` - it's just that this happens oh so often, and the tip is small. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $tpTitle="Helping you to improve your web site";

  $pgHeading="Site-Report.com - Helping you to improve your web site";

  $pgDesc="Helping you to improve your web site";

 $pgKeywords="site-report";

  ?>


<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>

 <title><?php echo $tpTitle ?></title>

 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>"></meta>

 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>"></meta>

</head>



 http://www.cre8asiteforums.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=4558
```

Comment: i say i know this function but how can i this function for this code? can i see example code?

Answer (score 1):

php header function got nothing to do with html tag "head" .

Comment: you dont understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `header()` function is not suitable for what you would like to do. You're merely looking for a variable:

index.php:

```
$title = 'My Page Title!';
$description = 'This is how I describe it.';
$keywords = 'page, title, describe';
```

header.php:

```
   <title>
      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>
   <title>
   <meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?>" /> 
   <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($keywords); ?>" />
```